# setting PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_GHOSTDRIVER_PATH_PROPERTY

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs, ghostdriver

I have difficulties setting the capability `PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_GHOSTDRIVER_PATH_PROPERTY` in my Java program correctly in order to use the [newest version of Ghostdriver from github](https://github.com/detro/ghostdriver) together with my installed phantomjs version (1.9.1)

Here is what I do in my Java program

```
DesiredCapabilities caps = DesiredCapabilities.phantomjs();
caps.setCapability(
    PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_EXECUTABLE_PATH_PROPERTY,
    "/xxx/phantomjs-1.9.1-linux-x86_64/bin/phantomjs" );
caps.setCapability(
    PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_GHOSTDRIVER_PATH_PROPERTY,
    "/xxx/ghostdriver/src/main.js");
WebDriver driver = new PhantomJSDriver(caps);
```

The selenium driver starts correctly, if i do not set the `PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_GHOSTDRIVER_PATH_PROPERTY`, but I get some errors in my tests that are supposed to be fixed in the current developer branch of ghostdriver. So i followed [this advice](https://github.com/detro/ghostdriver/issues/202#issuecomment-19808784) and set up the cuttent github version of ghostdriver.

However, now I get the following error:

```
[ERROR - 2013-07-12T10:22:36.897Z] GhostDriver - Main - Could not start Ghost Driver => {
  "message": "Could not start Ghost Driver",
  "line": 79,
  "sourceId": 140320571924032,
  "sourceURL": "/xxx/ghostdriver/src/main.js",
  "stack": "Error: Could not start Ghost Driver\n    at /xxx/ghostdriver/src/main.js:79",
  "stackArray": [
    {
      "sourceURL": "/xxx/ghostdriver/src/main.js",
      "line": 79
    }
  ]
}
```

My question is, does anyone know how to fix this? Must I change the `config.js` of ghostdriver somehow to make this work?

Info: I am [crossposting this also to the github issues of ghostdriver](https://github.com/detro/ghostdriver/issues/243).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I turns out, that this only works as expected for selenium version >= 2.33. I updated my selenium and this fixed the issue.

Comment: Oh wait, ignore me. Same error, different line number. Maybe it's different, maybe not.

Answer (score 5):

So I had the same problem, it was that the port I was attempting to use was already in use. Try a different port. i.e:

> phantomjs **--webdriver=8089** --webdriver-selenium-grid-hub=...

Answer (score 2):

Kill any phantomjs process that is running and try again:

```
ps aux | grep phantom
kill -9 <your phantom process id>
```

Then try running phantomjs again.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this problem by seeing if my port was being used with 
`netstat -tulnap` That shows you a list of all the ports in use. Find the one that phantomjs is using.
Then you can kill the process using `fuser <your-port-number>/tcp -k`.
For example, my port was 4444 so `fuser 444/tcp -k`