# Setting PhantomJSOptions.AddAdditionalCapability to reference local copy of ghostdriver

Tags: c#, selenium, phantomjs, ghostdriver

There appears to be an issue with ghostdriver in phantomjs that when an HTTP calls fails after clicking a button, the whole thing fails.

https://github.com/detro/ghostdriver/issues/202#issuecomment-19808784

The issue has been fixed and is in the main branch. Instructions are given on how to reference the new files and not use the ghostdriver as included with phantomjs.

The Java is here:
https://github.com/detro/ghostdriver/issues/243

and there appears to be a value

```
  PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_EXECUTABLE_PATH_PROPERTY
```

but that doesn't exist in C#

so have tried

```
  var opts = new PhantomJSOptions(); 
  opts.AddAdditionalCapability("phantomjs.ghostdriver.path.property", "c:\\path\\src\\main.js");
```

but no go, the output in the phantomjs still shows the older version

---

EDIT1:
This is different to the path to phantomJS which can be setby

```
 PhantomJSDriverService.CreateDefaultService("c:\path\to\phantomjs.exe")
```

I am trying to tell phantomjs to use a localversion of Ghostdriver not the ghostdriver included within phantomjs iteself.

---

EDIT2:
So digging around in the Java code files here
https://github.com/detro/ghostdriver/blob/master/binding/java/src/main/java/org/openqa/selenium/phantomjs/PhantomJSDriverService.java

I found the code that sets the Java static string

```
 public static final String PHANTOMJS_GHOSTDRIVER_PATH_PROPERTY = "phantomjs.ghostdriver.path";
```

which implies I was setting it wrong above, but still this doesn't work when corrected

```
var opts = new PhantomJSOptions(); 
opts.AddAdditionalCapability("phantomjs.ghostdriver.path", "c:\\path\\src\\main.js");
```

getting warmer though.....

Comment: so after digging through the source for .net and java versions of PhantomJSDriverService I do not think this is possible.

This is not possible in .net. There is no way to set the ghostdriver path.

I did manage to hack something together in code, only to find out I was hacking old webdriver code which failed the same as this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17613536/setting-phantomjsdriverservice-phantomjs-ghostdriver-path-property

The solution there is to update to 2.3.3. Am currently downloading the GIT repositry for selenium but at close to 2gb this is going to take me hours.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're right, there's no way to do this in the currently released binary version of the .NET bindings. However, a change [has just been made](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/detail?r=93acf0798e5b8a93e22fc9d20cc84c7faeef38f9) that will allow this. In the .NET bindings the code would look like the following:

```
var service = PhantomJSDriverService.CreateDefaultService(@"path\to\phantomjs.exe");
service.GhostDriverPath = @"path\to\ghostdriver\main.js";

var driver = new PhantomJSDriver(service);
```

The distinction between what is set via the `PhantomJSDriverService` and what is set via `PhantomJSOptions` can be summed up as follows. If the option is a command line argument to be passed into PhantomJS.exe, it should be set via the service; if it is an option for how GhostDriver acts, it should be set via the options class.

Comment: Only just finished downloading the source earlier and added something similar. I guess I better start downloading again and hope it will be ready by the morning :) Thanks Jim

Comment: The initial `git clone` is painful, but subsequent pulls tend to be pretty snappy. :)

Comment: Confirmed as working. Thank you. But in this build the service.proxy is ignored. But will investigate and post to the project board about that.

Answer (score 2):

You have at least two ways to specify phantomjs exec path.

**Use static method in PhantomJSDriverService**

```
var driver = new PhantomJSDriver(PhantomJSDriverService.CreateDefaultService("PHANTOMJSPATHHERE"));
```

**Use the appopriate constructor of PhantomJSDriver (takes a string)**

```
var driver = new PhantomJSDriver("PHANTOMJSPATHHERE");
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work. I believe this is to specify the path to the phantonjs.exe.

I am trying to set the path to the ghostdriver "\src\main.js" using the .Net equivilent of the Java :phantomjs.ghostdriver.path.property

Comment: have edited the original question to try and make this cleared.